# Join a table to itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the table i am using

```
EnquiryId     Day  CheckIn    Start  StartName   Destination  StayAt StayAtName
RH-0123201412  1  2014-12-25    99    Cochin     Trivandrum     3   Munnar
RH-0123201412  2  2014-12-26    3     Munnar     Trivandrum     3   Munnar
RH-0123201412  3  2014-12-27    3     Munnar     Trivandrum     8   Kanyakumari
```

Now the result i need is following:

```
EnquiryId     Day  CheckIn   Start  ComingFrom   GoinTo      StayAt StayAtName
RH-0123201412  1  2014-12-25  99      Cochin     KanyaKumari    3   Munnar
RH-0123201412  3  2014-12-27  3       Munnar     Trivandrum     8   Kanyakumari
```

I am trying following code bt its not wrking fully correct

```
SELECT q.Enquiry_Id
    ,q.Start
    ,q1.Stay_At
    ,q.Ckeck_In
    ,q1.Stay_At_Name
    ,q.Start_Name
FROM Quick_Plan q
    ,Quick_Plan q1
WHERE q.Enquiry_Id = 'RH-0123201412'
    AND q1.Enquiry_Id = 'RH-0123201412'
    AND q.Stay_At = q1.Start
```

from this query i am getting following result

```
EnquiryId    Start Stay_At CheckIn      StayAtName     Startname
RH-0123201412   99  3     2014-12-25    Munnar        Cochin Airport
RH-0123201412   99  8     2014-12-25    Kanyakumari   Cochin Airport
RH-0123201412   3   3     2014-12-26    Munnar        Munnar
RH-0123201412   3   8     2014-12-26    Kanyakumari   Munnar
```

Can anyone please suggest me what to do so that i get my required result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use `SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;` for the columns you need

Comment: what is the logic behind result set?

Comment: actually i have to create voucher in which have to tell client is coming from where staying where and going where like coming from cochin staying at munnar for 2 days and the moving to kanyakumari and if kanyakumari is the last stay at place then going to final destination that is trivandrum .

Comment: @Kamna How do we know that client came from Cochin? How do we know that client move to Kanyakumari (not to Munnar)?

Comment: The desired output is clear to you but not at all to those who aren't familiar with the problem. Eg there's no indication that Start/Stay_At are Foreign Keys, especially since if they are, your data isn't normalised correctly (Why store an Id and a string name repeatedly through the table? Use the Id and have a `Locations` table). Try reading your question again and assuming no knowledge. I think you'll see it's not very clear

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @Parado please see the original table in which i mention the start place and the place where client stay and final destination also because munnar is his stay place and next day his start place is munnar and stay place is Kanyakumari and after that there is no record means tour ends so the final place is trivandrum

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after or not? If not what are you wanting to happen?

```
SELECT q.Enquiry_Id
,q.Start
,Max(q.Stay_At) Stay_At
,Max(q.Ckeck_In) Check_in
,Max(q.Stay_At_Name) Stay_At_Name
,q.Start_Name
FROM Quick_Plan q
WHERE q.Enquiry_Id = 'RH-0123201412'
group by Enquiry_Id, Start, Startname
```